# How to call *.ashx handler in asp.net 4.0 Routing

Tags: asp.net, routes, httphandler, handler

I am working in ASP.net 4.0 with Routing site and it is not in MVC Architecture.
Here i got a big problem i.e. i can't call any handler file through routing.

I write this code in global.asax page

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{language}/{*page}", new CustomRouteHandler()));
    }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

and in CustomRouteHandler class

```
    public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string language = TemplateControlExtension.GetString(null, requestContext.RouteData.Values["language"]).ToLower();
        string page = TemplateControlExtension.GetString(null, requestContext.RouteData.Values["page"]).ToLower();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(page))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/" + language + "/default.aspx");
        }

        string VirtualPath = "~/" + page;

        if (language != null)
        {
            TemplateControlExtension.Language = language;
        }

        return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;
    }
}
```

While i am calling any handler file in this site it throws an error i.e.

```
Type 'Captcha' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.
```

My Question is that how we can call handler files in this site??

What modification wants this route code??

Comment: Is it catpcha a page? seems that your route is taking this request and doesn't return the right value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Code

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class HttpHandlerRouteHandler<T> : IRouteHandler where T : IHttpHandler, new() {

  public HttpHandlerRouteHandler() { }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
    return new T();
  }
}

public class HttpHandlerRouteHandler : IRouteHandler {

  private string _VirtualPath;

  public HttpHandlerRouteHandler(string virtualPath) {
    this._VirtualPath = virtualPath;
  }

  public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
    return (IHttpHandler) BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(this._VirtualPath, typeof(IHttpHandler));
  }

}
```